# Class in python instances

Tags: python, windows, eclipse, class, methods

```
class fase1(): 
   def __init__ (self, num, date, desc) 
       self.num = num 
       self.date = date 
       self.desc = desc 

class fase2(fase1): 
   def __init__(self, ele): 
      self.ele = [ele,[]] 
    def __str__(self): 
      return self.ele
    def addfase2(self, num, date, desc): 
      newfase = fase1() 
      self.ele[1].append(newfase) 


namefase2 = "FASE" 
cload = fase2 
cload.ele = namefase2 
cload.addfase2(10,"date","Desc")
```

when print ...

```
['FASE',[<__main__.fase1 instance at 0x01C2BEB8>]]
```

can anyone help me please?

Comment: Help with what? What isn't working?

Comment: Your `__str__` is doing exactly what you programmed it to do

Comment: add `__str__` to `fase1` and you wont get the `<__main__.fase1 instance at 0x01C2BEB8>` in the output.

Answer (score 0):

you have an array containing your `fase1` object, which isn't initialized in your `addfase2` method (as you'd probably want)

```
def addfase2(self, num, date, desc): 
    newfase = fase1(num, date, desc)
```

also if you add a `__str__` method to `fase1`, you won't see anymore the object repr

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.desc + ' ' + self.num + ' ' + self.date
```

or something like that

Comment: sorry all, my keyboard is going nuts. if somebody could edit my post with the correct syntax around str, addfase2 etc, that would be absolutely great! thanks!